# Determining whether a folder is in a file path

Tags: python, regex, filepath

I am working on a backup script in Python, and would like it to be able to ignore folders. I therefore have a list of folders to be ignored, ie `['Folder 1', 'Folder3']`. I am using `os.walk`, and am trying to get it to skip any folder in the ignored folders list or that has any of the ignored folders as a parent directory. Has anyone done this before, as examples I've seen don't seem to work and often end up creating an empty folder?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925056/a-python-walker-that-can-ignore-directories/925291#925291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again.

So, iterate through your list and remove entries that match.

Answer (score 0):

After the following statement

```
folders = [path+'/'+dir for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(base) 
                                   for dir in dirs 
                                     if dir not in ['Folder 1', 'Folder3', ...]]
```

the variable `folders` should contain the folders you are interested in.

Edit1: `... + '/' + ...` works just in Unix-like OS. I think there is a `os.path.join` which does the same job platform indepentently

Edit2: If you want to exclude all Subdirectories of the directories to be excluded, you can try the following:

```
exclusions = ['Folder 1', 'Folder3', ...]
folders = [path+'/'+dir for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(base)
                        if not any([f in path for f in exclusions])
                        for dir in dirs 
                        if dir not in exclusions
          ]
```